# Can't add custom template to sonata_type_model many_to_many

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Can't add custom template to sonata_type_model many_to_many relation.
I want to override standart template `edit_orm_many_to_many.html.twig`

Wrote something like this:

```
        ->add('forms', 'sonata_type_model', array('expanded' => true,
                                                  'multiple' => true,
                                                  'query' => $query,
                                                  'template' => 'MyBundle:Default:edit_orm_many_to_many.html.twig'
                                                  ));
```

But I can't recieve any reaction. I can add `'template' => 'qwe'` and I still see standart template, notify about errors not appear. Looks  like option template not working.

**UPDATE**: Any ideas will very useful

Comment: do you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change template in formMapper. This dosen't works that way with forms. You need to use form theming. Check this out [Sonata Admin Bundle - Form type: sonata_type_collection - custom template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501022/sonata-admin-bundle-form-type-sonata-type-collection-custom-template) or this: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/1104